# CefSharp - Way to hide script errors and url

Tags: javascript, winforms, url, chromium, cefsharp

Does someone know how to hide script errors and url that appears when hovering over a link?

Image of hover block

[image: 1]

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What's the image supposed to be of? Remember nobody here can see your application. A snippet of an image doesn't tell us much

Comment: @amaitland It's not the issue within the application code its the issue with how the cefsharp works. Even tho I added settings.LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Disable; in the settings I still see console errors on the bottom left and I see the link when I hover like on the screenshot above. Is there a way to hide this?

Comment: The `ChromiumWebBrowser` instance doesn't display console messages by default, it's up to the embedded to implement this functionality. If your application is showing it then it's up to you to remove it. How exactly are we supposed to know the screenshot above is a link hover? It's a white box with a single line of text. Could be anything. Tool tips can be customised by implementing https://cefsharp.github.io/api/110.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_Handler_DisplayHandler_OnTooltipChanged.htm

Comment: @amaitland I have implemented a new displayHandler but when I return true for the tooltip it doesn't do anything, I still see the URL.

https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/VtBxFKmt9Jb4.png?o=1
I even returned false and changed text before that but without any luck

Comment: For some reason I though you were using `WPF`. Looks like you are actually using `WinForms`. The `API` only supports customising `WPF` tooltips, there's no supported `API` for `WinForms`. You'll probably have to inject javascript into each page to hide/remove the tooltip.